# Installation of the F# compiler on Windows 10

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I followed the directions on http://fsharp.org/use/windows/ 
option 2
Step 1 ok : VS Code is installed (latest ver)
Step 2 not ok  ext install Ionide-fsharp does not work so installed using extensions in VS Code , found ionide-fsharp installed it ok and followed all instructions on ionidwe-fsharp page

Created a .fs file with the following code;
printfn "Hello World to F# language "

ran code and got:

> error FS0193: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: If you are on windows anyway I would start with installing VS2017 as it will give you msbuild15 (besides fsc).

Answer (score 3):

If you read the option 2 carefully, you will see that it says:

```
You will also need to install the free F# compiler and command line tools in Step 4.
```

If you scroll down to option 4, you'll see its suboption A (the simplest) recommends installing [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) and selecting F# in the list of components to install.

---

Since you are only beginning to learn F#, it is very likely that you will return to StackOverflow to ask more questions in the future. When you do, please make sure that your questions are phrased and formatted clearly. In particular, pay attention to punctuation and grammar. Clumsily crafted questions are very hard to understand, and a lot of people will just elect not to answer them at all. By crafting your question carefully, you will increase your chance of getting a useful answer.

For some more specific guidance, refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks.  I installed Visual Studio Build Tools.  The F# option was not one of the choices.  Installed anyway and found an F# component when modifying VS.  After the install restarted the PC -> started VS code -> ran the .fs code to print the Hello World code -> received the same error